# Problema al intentar subir una App por Xcode

Tags: nativescript

Buenas días compañeros¡ tengo un problema al ejecutar desde Xcode:

```
Product - Archive - Distribute App
```

Después de tener en orden las licencias y lo que pide para el `Signing`
me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Code signing "TNSMLKitCamera.framework" failed.
```

Al ir al sitio donde se generó este error, y el fichero que se llama `IDEDistributionPipeline.log` pone lo siguiente:

```
2019-05-23 09:01:47 +0000  /var/folders/b7/_7dsbb397p5_w5wncpyx195r0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.5rA/Root/Payload/appBarco.app/app/app/nativescript-plugin-firebase/platforms/ios/TNSMLKitCamera.framework: code object is not signed at all
2019-05-23 09:01:47 +0000  /usr/bin/codesign exited with 1
```

Esta es la version de mi Xcode `Version 10.1 (10B61)`.
Que se ejecuta en un Mac `macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6`

mi `package.json`:

```
  {
    "nativescript": {
        "id": "org.adealoxica.appbarco",
        "tns-android": {
            "version": "5.2.1"
        },
        "tns-ios": {
            "version": "4.2.0"
        }
    },
    "description": "AppBarco Application",
    "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
    "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/http": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
        "nativescript-angular": "~7.2.1",
        "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^7.7.0",
        "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
        "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
        "rxjs": "~6.3.0",
        "tns-core-modules": "~5.2.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
        "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.5.0",
        "@ngtools/webpack": "~7.2.0",
        "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.8.0",
        "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~0.20.0"
    },
    "gitHead": "f548ec926e75201ab1b7c4a3a7ceefe7a4db15af",
    "readme": "AppBarco Application"
}
```

Si necesitas algo mas, decidme por favor. Es la primera vez que subo algo a AppStore y esta siendo doloroso. Muchas gracias de antemano.

ACTUALIZACION.

No se si tendrá que ver a la hora de hacer el `Archive` pero en mi `build.xcconfig` que esta en la carpeta `App_Resources\ios\build.xconfig.`

tengo lo siguiente:

```
 // You can add custom settings here
// for example you can uncomment the following line to force distribution code signing
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iOS Distribution;
// To build for device with XCode 8 you need to specify your development team.
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = ramon pereira prieto;
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME = LaunchImage;
```

Por defecto venían comentado el `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM`y el `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY`. 
¿Quizá pueda ser el error de intentar hacerlo automáticamente desde Xcode?

FOTO:
[image: Error de Signing]

Foto de `Build Settings`
[image: Code Signing]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que añadir una cuenta para firmar tu aplicación para ello una vez abierto el proyecto con xcode pincha sobre directorio padre de tu aplicación, tiene que tener el nombre de tu aplicación y un icono azul con el símbolo de xcode. Hecho esto the aparecerán dos opciones, project y targets. Haz click en el elemento de Targets esta vez con el icono de tu aplicación. Una vez tengas las opciones abiertas en el apartado `signing` debes añadir o elegir una cuenta de iPhone developer y hecho esto ya te debería dejar compilar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez hecho esto ya debería estar solucionado el error que comentas y ya te sería posible lanzar la aplicación a algún dispositivo conectado. Para continuar con la subida de tu aplicación a la apple store puedes seguir el siguiente tutorial https://instabug.com/blog/how-to-submit-app-to-app-store/

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @David. Pero el problema es que ya tenia supuestamente una Apple ID seleccionada... pero me daba un error al hacer el 'Archive' y después 'Distribution App', me decía que no podía ser Automático el inicio de sesión. Voy a probar de nuevo y te comento exactamente lo que me dice. Mil gracias de nuevo por responder.

Comment: El error que te da es de firma. Prueba sino a seleccionar en `File > Project settings > Build System'` la opción `Legacy Build System`. También asegurate que tu Apple ID esté asociado y tenga permisos con tu aplicación

Comment: Vale, ya tengo el `Legacy Build System` seleccionado. Probé de nuevo, pero me lanza este mismo error siempre: `fse.node has conflicting provisioning settings`. y seguidamente `fse.node is automatically signed for distribution, but a conflicting code signing identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code signing identity value to "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor`.

Comment: Si tienes alguna version de tu app instalada en el iphone prueba a desinstalarla antes de instalar la nueva porque podría ser un problema de conflicto de firmas. Prueba también lo que te dice el error, en la imagen que te puse en la respuesta en la fila donde se marcan el punto 2 y 3 si te fijas hay una pestaña que se llama `Build Settings`, ves ahi y prueba a cambiar en el apartado signing el `code signing identity` con el valor que te especifica el error y a ver si hay suerte

Comment: Vale probare a hacerlo así. Fijate que actualice mi pregunta... voy a subir otra imagen con la parte de `Build Settings`.